# MAUI .net C# from Visual Studio for PC : error missing parameter 'path2' when publishing

Tags: c#, ios, .net, maui, publish

I am currently engaged in the development of a .NET C# MAUI application for both Android and iOS platforms, using Visual Studio 2022 for PC. The application executes flawlessly on my MacBook Air within the iOS Simulator environment.

However, encountering a challenge arises when attempting to publish the application as an .ipa file through the conventional process of right-clicking on the project and selecting 'Publish.' This operation extends over a prolonged duration, and approximately 15 minutes into the process, an error surfaces with the following message:

```
Unable to build an iOS archive for 'XXXXX_app'. The process cannot be executed on an XMA server. MessagingRemoteException: An error occurred on client Build16460 while executing a reply for the topic xvs/build/16.4.60/execute-task/{AppName}/10d848a002fCompileEntitlements. 

ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: path2.
```

Regrettably, the error message provides no additional contextual information. I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions from the community to address this matter.

Here is the screenshot of the error message :

[image]

Comment: You can check this document about [Publish a .NET MAUI app for iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/deployment/?view=net-maui-8.0).

Comment: Thanks. I've checked everything, it seems correct... but problem still here :(

Comment: It could be that the XMA server is unable to unzip the app bundle that is sent from the Windows machine. This could happen if the app bundle is corrupted or has an invalid format. A possible solution is to remove the bin/obj folder, delete the XMA cache folder and pair to mac again then archive the app1. You may also need to re-download the certificate and provisioning profile after cleaning the XMA cache folder

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I have created a brand new projet, and copy/past all my XAML ans CS files, reinstall nugets, and now it works... so I don't know exactely what was wrong but it's ok now. Thanks for your help